# how does gem installation works ? how did gem get the installation files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

when I wanted to install [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html), I have been told to install ruby on my machine, ok fine.

then all I had to do is to run the following code

```
gem install sass
```

and now I am done, and I have SASS installed

my question is in general..

**How did gem knows what SASS is, and from where did it get it ?**

**It is a cool thing but I just want to know what happened behind the scenes ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/) is a [package manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) like many others. It depends on a central repository to host installable packages. The command line tool fetches these packages from the central repository and installs them.

See [RubyGems FAQ](http://guides.rubygems.org/faqs/) and [Introduction](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/).

Comment: can you please add some info about what happens during the installation ? I want to only copy a gem and all its dependencies into a folder, without affecting any of my system settings, environment variables etc. Will the gem installation to that folder help me to get what i want ? Btw, that introduction link page is not working - This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: @sidsmith You are looking for bundle install. Specify the gems you want to install in your working directory in a Gemfile. Then do a bundle install. Check out this site for more help: bundler.io